# Drunk Cycling Laws

Tags: legal, bicycles, alcohol

As we all know, almost all parts of the world have very specific laws regarding drunk driving they specify a certain amount of blood alcohol content that is permissible to be a in state fit to drive. However, these laws are much less clearer when it comes to cycling under the influence. For example, the UK has [cycling laws](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code/rules-for-cyclists-59-to-82) that prohibit riding a bicycle "when under the influence of drink or drugs, including medicine." However this does not specify a particular limit of blood alcohol content that is permissible, making it harder to enforce.

My question, therefore, is: as a tourist, are there any places in the world to be aware of where cycling while drunk is an offence that is clearly defined by law, and also has specific penalties associated with violations of such a law?

Comment: This is an interesting academic question, but I fear you ask it instead for practical reasons.  Drunk cycling is more dangerous than drunk driving because you are less well protected from the harm of a collision.  If you're intoxicated to the point where you may run afoul of the law, then you're too intoxicated to even think about riding a bike.  Walk, or take transit, or take a cab.

Comment: This is pretty broad. A number of places (e.g. [California](https://www.shouselaw.com/cycling-biking-under-influence.html)) make cycling while under the influence illegal, with specific penalties, but they don't always have a per se BAC threshold—it's just up to the legal system to prove you're intoxicated. [Some US states](https://www.avvo.com/legal-guides/ugc/a-state-by-state-guide-to-biking-under-the-influence) just apply their driving DUI laws to bicycles too, so yes, such places exist. I'm not really sure how this can be answered without considering every legal jurisdiction in the world.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie you have the point backwards.  The principal argument against drink-driving is the risk of harm to *others*, which is likely lower for a cyclist than any other road user.  By this measure, drink-cycling is less dangerous than drink-driving, not more so.  That doesn't mean it's a good idea to tootle home from the pub on your bike, but it's a *vastly* better idea than getting on the front of a motorbike, or (worse still) behind the wheel of a car.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie I understand your concern, but I do not even have a bicycle, which would make it a bit hard for me to apply what I learn from this question into practical usage.

Comment: Don't drink and cycle, whenever, wherever, either as a local or a tourist; even if not completely prohibited.

Comment: @MadHatter You're not wrong, but I think the desire for self-preservation here would make one reluctant to drunk-cycle.  Note though that it is still possible to cause significant harm with a bicycle, especially to pedestrians.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not answer for the rest of the word but did check it for the country where cycling is the most common way of transport.

[This site (run by the Dutch police)](https://www.vraaghetdepolitie.nl/drank-en-drugs/alcohol-en-verkeer/hoeveel-alcohol-mag-je-drinken-als-je-nog-een-fiets-of-brommer-moet-besturen.html) is very clear about it.

> Op de fiets mag je maximaal 0,5 promille alcohol in je bloed hebben. Dat zijn ongeveer twee glazen.
>
> On the bike you are allowed a maximum of 0.5 promille alcohol in your blood. That is about two glasses.

As a Dutch person who has lived in the country for more than 50 years, I have never heard of a cyclist being tested for alcohol as a routine test, nor of having been banned of getting on with cycling unless clearly drunk.
So, yes, it is in the law, but no, it is not active.
That is unless you are involved in an accident and they have reasons to suspect your alcohol consumption.